# Angular know if dynamic ng-template is loaded

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic component loader that works.
And now I need to know when it is loaded to display it (to know when all images are download before display it).
But the event binding 'loaded' does not exists on 'ng-template'.

So is it possible to do know if 'ng-template' is fully loaded, or is it possible to do dynamic component display with loaded event binding in another way ?

Thank you for your help :)

---

Actually dynamic template implementation (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) :

Template :

```
<div class="container" [ngClass]="{loaded : loaded}">
    <div class="loading-logo" [ngClass]="{show : !loaded}">
        <img class="screen-element image" [src]="screen.agency.logo">
    </div>
    <ng-template appTemplate class="screen-element template"></ng-template>
</div>
```

Style :

```
:host,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:not(.loaded) {
  position: relative;
}

.loading-logo {
  display: none;
}

.loading-logo.show {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.screen-element.image {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
}

.screen-element.template {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Typescript :

```
@ViewChild(TemplateDirective, { static: true }) templateHost!: TemplateDirective;
screen: Screen = {...}
currentElementIndex = -1;
loaded = false;

constructor(private screenService: ScreenService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    ...
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadScreen();
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

loadScreen(): void {}

async loadElementComponent() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to know? screen?.agency?.logo should work?

Comment: Hi @MikeOne, The images loading I was talking is about images inside the ngTemplate node (wich is dunamically filled with the component I initiate in the typescript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I get no answer, I search a lot and find a solution (not relly clean from my viewpoint but well, it works).

I add an output (EventEmitter) in the called component, and emit 'isLoaded = true' in 'ngAfterViewInit'.

```
export class CalledComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, TemplateComponent {

  isLoaded = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.isLoaded.emit(true);
  }
}
```

So I can, from my display component, subscribe and know when it is loaded.

```
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<CalledComponent>(componentToCall);
//componentRef.instance.input = 'input;
componentRef.instance.isLoaded.subscribe(isLoaded => this.loaded = isLoaded);
```